# How does one calculate how to dilute a solution to working strength?

Tags: pcr, gel-electrophoresis

If I'm loading a 3.5ul PCR onto an agarose gel, how do I calculate how much of the 6x loading dye to add?

Answer (score 2):

Since its 6x (6 times concentrated), you have to dilute it 1:6, so you add 1ul of 6x dye for every 5ul of reaction.

5 +1=6ul final volume

6ul final volume / 6x concentrated = 1x working concentration

Now the dye is diluted down to a 1x(working) strength.

Answer (score 0):

You want to dilute concentrations to 1x, therefore a 1:6 ratio for dye:reaction.